# Try to connect LDAP server and get "The distinguished name contains invalid syntax"

Tags: c#, ldap

I try to connect to LDAP server using SSL and get the error

> The distinguished name contains invalid syntax

Code:

```
string userName = "1n07op"          

LdapDirectoryIdentifier ldi = new LdapDirectoryIdentifier("myddc01.swinfra.net",636);

LdapConnection ldapConnection = new LdapConnection(ldi);      
ldapConnection.Credential = new NetworkCredential(userName, password);
ldapConnection.SessionOptions.SecureSocketLayer = true;
ldapConnection.SessionOptions.ProtocolVersion = 3;
ldapConnection.SessionOptions.VerifyServerCertificate = new VerifyServerCertificateCallback(ServerCallBack);
ldapConnection.AuthType = AuthType.Basic;

ldapConnection.Bind();
ldapConnection.Dispose();

return true;
```

Can anyone help my solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the username "1n07op", you need to include the type of this attribute you are using, for example `cn, ou, uid, sn` plus the full `dn`  where your user exists in the ldap,  thus, to successfully bind to your ldap you will need to have your username set to something like this:

```
String userName="uid=1n07op,ou=people,ou=company,ou=com"
```